# Settings, Appearance and Plugins not Showing in WordPress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, wp-admin

[image]Settings, Appearance and plugins are not showing in WordPress admin panel though the site is running.

I have gone through a lot of documentation and tried changing wp-config file but in vain

Comment: Are you logged in as super admin ? it might be possible is some user management role system on your site

Comment: @Dhruv Yes, I have logged in as a super admin but I am unable to see these options in the sidebar of admin panel

Comment: please check the attached screenshot. there is no option of settings, appearance and plugins

Comment: then how you enable the "tab responsive" plugin

Comment: I think some plugin caused this issue as this issue was not occurring before

Comment: Exactly i just wanted to say this

Comment: If this project is in local system then try to remove plugin from directory one by one i'm sure you will got the solution very soon